# Word 2010 Mail Merge Suppress Blank Conditional Mergefields

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, mail-merge, conditional-statements

I cannot get a conditional Mail Merge to suppress blank lines in a relatively clean and efficient way. The only solution I have found is one I am not willing to use yet as I feel there may be a better way.

Right now, my conditional merge looks like this:

[image]

However, this is not suppressing the values that are blank and a bunch of blank lines are showing up on the letter.

I have tried forcing a `<line_break>` or `<paragraph_break>` to trick word into using the default blank suppression. I have also tried removing the `<paragraph break>` after each line altogether.

I understand from [this helpful site](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/mailmerge/mmergeiffields.htm) that I can do a kind of multiple condition statement, but also know that statement will look *very ugly, very quickly* with the amount of conditions that I have.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can suppress the blanks line in such a way as to be clean and neat (relatively) and that other people can easily understand going forward?

Comment: I ended up solving this by returning Null in the 2nd field if the first field was false for each one in the data query in my Access. The query is stored in an Excel sheet for the mail merge. Then I just listed the field names in the Word document, in consecutive lines and it now suppresses blanks by default :)  Leaving this open for now in case others have any insights .

Answer (score 1):

To suppress blank lines when mail merge fields in a mail merge main document are empty create the following code in a **VBA Module**.

```
Sub SuppressBlankLines() 
 ActiveDocument.MailMerge.SuppressBlankLines = True 
End Sub
```

If "Developer" is not active/visible in your Word document you will need to enable this from **File** -> **Options** -> **Customize Ribbon** ('tick' Developer box). This will allow you to select the **Visual Basic** development system and add a Module.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing this kind of problem by manipulating the data source (e.g. using a query) is usually the best way forward. AFAICS that is what you have now done.

As background, not all blanks in MailMerge are treated as blank for the purpose of blank line suppression. Ordinary typed white space such as spaces and tabs are treated as blank. MERGEFIELD fields that have a blank result are treated as blank. But the result of an IF field is never treated as blank.

I am assuming that the logic you require is along the following lines

```
If ( ext_b1 is False or borrower_1 is blank )
  don't insert anything, not even a blank line
Else (i.e. ext_b1 is True and borrower_1 is not blank )
  insert borrower_1 followed by a paragraph mark
End If
```

If so, and ext_b1 is always the same non-blank value when it is "not False" *and* borrower_1 is never more than about 120 characters long (that's OTTOMH, you should check), you can use a wildcarding trick to simplify the IF test and make the field coding a bit simpler:

```
{ IF "{ MERGEFIELD ext_b1 }{ MERGEFIELD borrower_1 }" = "True?*" "{ MERGEFIELD borrower_1 }" "" }
{ IF "{ MERGEFIELD ext_b2 }{ MERGEFIELD borrower_2 }" = "True?*" "{ MERGEFIELD borrower_2 }" "" }
```

Except that doesn't actually eliminate the paragraph mark when ext_b1 is False or borrower_1 is blank. To deal with that, what you can do is insert the paragraph mark inside the If "is true result" and put all the { } IF fields on one line, like this:

```
{ IF "{ MERGEFIELD ext_b1 }{ MERGEFIELD borrower_1 }" = "True?*" "{ MERGEFIELD borrower_1 }
" "" }{ IF "{ MERGEFIELD ext_b2 }{ MERGEFIELD borrower_2 }" = "True?*" "{ MERGEFIELD borrower_2 }
" "" }
```

To make that a little clearer (I hope), you can also modify the field code layout by putting paragraph marks inside the IF but outside the result texts of the IF. These marks won't be part of the result. You also don't need the "false" result. so  e.g.

```
{ IF "{ MERGEFIELD ext_b1 }{ MERGEFIELD borrower_1 }" = "True?*" 
"{ MERGEFIELD borrower_1 }
" }{ IF "{ MERGEFIELD ext_b2 }{ MERGEFIELD borrower_2 }" = "True?*" 
"{ MERGEFIELD borrower_2 }
" }
```

A problem with modifying the layout in this way is that the amount of vertical space occupied by the field expression changes depending on whether the user has field codes or field results displayed, so switching from one view to the other can be disconcerting (especially in a large document, where Word may also spend time repaginating when you toggle field code display on and off.)